# debugging contract test cases in spring cloud contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a question related to spring cloud contract framework.Is it possible to debug the test cases which are auto-generated by spring cloud contracts. usually I do gradle build to execute the contracts.But to understand the actual problem, I would like to do debug and see the results.

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Cloud Contract Plugin generates standard Junit test files based on your contracts. For Maven you can find these in the `target/generated-test-sources/contracts` directory (Gradle will have similar output in the `build` directory).

When opening the files in this directory, you can have a look at the generated code. If the intention is to debug these tests, they can be copy/pasted from this directory into the actual test sources directory in your project. Then you can directly run the tests in debug mode (as previously pointed out by Marcin). To avoid the copy/pasting, add the `target/generated-test-sources/contracts` directory as test sources folder in your IDE.